# How to price option with limited information?

Tags: finance, estimation

You have a call option on a security worth 100 now that will either be worth 110 or 95 dollars at a future date. The strike of this option is 105. What is an estimated value of this call option?

Comment: What are your own ideas?

Comment: Hey sorry I should have put this down. My thought process was the option has a 50-50 chance of ending up at 110 or 95. So then the payoff of the option will either be 5 or 0 with a strike of 105. So then the value is 1/2 * 5 + 1/2 * 0 = 2.5.

Comment: I'm not using the current value of 100 in my calculation though so I feel I might be missing something.

Comment: You are probably expected to use the "No arbitrage principle".  How many shares and what cash position at the future date (fractions allowed) would replicate the option outcomes?  What would getting to that future position cost you now?  Have you taken interest rates into account?

Answer (score 1):

$d=0.95$  and $u = 1.1$

Risk Neutral probability is $\pi_u = \frac{1+r-d}{u-d} = \frac{1}{3}$ assuming risk free rate is 0.0

Then $\pi_d = \frac{2}{3}$

$c_u = 110-105 = 5$ and $c_d = max(95-105,0) = 0$

Thus the value of the call option is $ = \dfrac{\pi_u\times c_u + \pi_d\times c_d}{(1+r)} = \frac{1}{3}.5 + \frac{2}{3}.0 = \frac{5}{3}$